# Can not install RealmSwift with cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoa, realm, swift3

Every time I am trying to install RealmSwift with cocoapods gives me 
`[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
sh build.sh cocoapods-setup` error. I have updated to xcode 8 and cocoapods to 1.1.0 
however when I try from another mac with older cocoa RealmSwift 1.0.2 is getting installed.

Please help

Comment: What does your podfile look like? Can you please add it to your question?

Comment: A) Please share your Podfile. B) Please be sure to run `pod repo update` before installing. CocoaPods no longer does this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and hit this command

```
$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods
```

It will simply update CocoaPods version of your system. And then try to install Realm using this.

Add this piece of code to pods file,

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3' # or '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

It will add Realm for your latest swift version.